# Criteria API: query.from returns only null

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm pretty new to Criteria API, as a matter of fact I just pushed our latest project to JBoss 6 and JPA 2.0 just for the Criteria API.

Now I am trying to get the easiest query running, but somehow without success:

Without Criteria API it works without problems (Msv being my entity class):

```
Msv someMsv = manager.find(Msv.class, 1234L);
System.out.println(someMsv);
```

The criteria stuff however does not give me any results from the DB:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Msv> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Msv.class);
Root<Msv> from = criteriaQuery.from(Msv.class);
// this returns null! /\
Path<Msv> pk = from.get("PK_MSV_NR");
Expression<Boolean> exp = builder.equal(pk, 1234L);
CriteriaQuery<Msv> select = criteriaQuery.select(from).where(exp);
[...]
```

When running the second code snipped I get a NullPointerException thrown on line 5 (Path pk ...), hence the above cireriaQuery.from returns null.

Did I miss something essential, or what is the problem here? The first snippet is able to pull the correct entry from the DB and syso it, so I figured it is not a problem with my persistance config but rather with my Criteria API code. But that one I pulled from a tutorial basically line by line...

*Tech: I am using hibernate-3.6.6, hibernate-jpa-2.0-cr, jboss-as-6.0.0 and oracle11.*

**EDIT:**
Looked into this some more and discovered the following: it is not actually *criteriaQuery.from(...)* that produces null. The NullPointerException is not thrown because *.get()* is called on null, but is *actually thrown by/in .get() method*. I can for the life of me not see why however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, I finally found out what I did wrong. As I let eclipse generate the entity classes for me I wasn't paying enough attention to the nomenclature of their fields.

The field I was looking for is called 'PK_MSV_NR' in the database, however eclipse named it 'pkMsvNr' in the entity class. Hence the problem.

Still, I think it is kind of strange behavior to throw a NullPointerException off of this. There's really not much null pointing going on here...

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should use the JPA 2 static metamodel classes, they give you compile-time safety. See [Hibernate Metamodel Generator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html) for the hibernate version.

Comment: I'm about to implement just that. I just thought that at first I'd rather not start with all the new APIs at once, and get some plain Criteria API up and running before worrying about meta model generation... The latter turns out to be quite straightforward though.